# Array of Objects being sent as one Object

Tags: c#, arrays, coffeescript

I have never encountered an issue like this before (if I had a dollar for every time I said that), so I'll do my best to explain it fully.

For this application I'm building, I'm using CoffeeScript for the client side code, and C# for the server side code.

On the client side I have an array named **products**. This holds a product name, as well as an id for that product.

I'm simply trying to send this array to the server. Here is what the client is doing:

```
 $http.put("#{$config.serverAddress}UserChoice/GetTotalScoreForProducts?productIDList=" 
+ _.pluck(products, 'id')
).success (response) ->
    console.log "SUCCESS"
    console.log response
  .error ->
    console.log 'error'
```

Here is the method on the server. Right now I'm just debugging this issue, so there is just a variable there for displaying the length of the array that I'm passing:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public void GetTotalScoreForProducts([FromUri] object[] productIDList)
    {
        int length = productIDList.Length;
    }
```

When debugging, the `object[] productIDList` only contains one object. However, that one object consists of **both** of the id's from the array:

[image]

So for some reason, the two seperate array objects are being put into one object.

The issue seems to be with how I'm passing the **products** array to the server, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: After trying T.Rahgooy's solution:

[image]

EDIT: After hard coding in values to the URL:

[image]

**EDIT: It's working now! Here's the working code!**

```
$http.put("#{$config.serverAddress}UserChoice/GetTotalScoreForProducts?productIDList=" 
+ _.pluck(products, 'id').join(&productIDList=)
).success (response) ->
    console.log "SUCCESS"
    console.log response
  .error ->
    console.log 'error'
```

[image]

**Thanks for helping me out T.Rahgooy =)**

Answer (score 1):

You are sending `querystring: ? productIDList=x,y`, it should be `querystring: ? productIDList=x &productIDList=y` to receive as an array.

```
$http.put("#{$config.serverAddress}UserChoice/GetTotalScoreForProducts?" 
  + _.map(products, (x)->"productIDList=" + x.id + "&").join(' ')
).success (response) ->
console.log "SUCCESS"
console.log response
.error ->
console.log 'error'
```

Comment: I just tried this solution a moment ago. the `int length` variable in the C# code is coming up as zero now, so nothing seems to be getting passed now. I'll look more into the `_.map` function to see what I can find.

Comment: I change the code, check it now. Can you check the query string, if it's in expected format?

Comment: Just tried that. Afraid it's still returning zero. I added another screenshot to the original post so you can see what it's returning

Comment: is this with last change `_.map(products, (x)->"productIDList=" + x.id + "&").join(' ')`?

Comment: Yes. The server still seems to just be accepting one object.

Comment: can you please set the hard coded url like this `serveraddress/UserChoice/GetTotalScoreForProducts?productIDList=A&productIDList=B` and test what is received. It should send array of `{"A","B"} `

Comment: Okay, when I did that, only "A" appeared. I made another edit to the OP so you can see.

Comment: it's wired, I created a tiny example for it and its works fine, but when I copied the url from my previous comment, it just receives `A`. I think there is some invisible characters in previous comment url because when I inspect it, it receives as : `?productIDList=A&productIDList%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B=B`. But when I type  `?productIDList=A&productIDList=B`, and do not copy it, it's works fine

Comment: So get this. I went back to try using `_.pluck()` again. I added `.join('&productIDList=')` to it and changed `productIDList` to an `int` array and it's working now.

Comment: Now matter how, you must send `?productIDList=A&productIDList=B` instead of `?productIDList=A,B`. Anyway I'm glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

`_.pluck` according to [this link](https://autotelicum.github.io/Smooth-CoffeeScript/literate/underscore.html#pluck) does exactly what you see in your debug window. It creates a comma separated list of your `products` array.

If you want to have one ID for every product you will have to build your URI to look like

```
#{$config.serverAddress}UserChoice/GetTotalScoreForProducts?productIDList=Email%20Gateway&productIDList=Truekey&..."
```